# Why Named Function Expression itself cannot assign Name to another Value?

Tags: javascript, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

```
var functionVariable = function functionExpressionName() {
    functionExpressionName = 1;
    console.log(functionExpressionName) // function
};

functionVariable();
```

If You run this example you can see we can not reassign to ***functionExpressionName*** anything. 
But this is also interesting we can reddeclare ***functionExpressionName*** and after this we can assign anything to ***functionExpressionName***

```
var functionVariable = function functionExpressionName() {
    function functionExpressionName() {

    }

    functionExpressionName = 1;
    console.log(functionExpressionName); // 1
};

functionVariable();
```

Comment: Yeah that's look like but in there not say Function Expression and when I search I don't found in stackoverflow. Sorry about that I close question :)

Comment: Why U delete first comment? :d

Comment: Which comment do you mean?

Comment: Link to main question

Comment: The “possible duplicate” comments get deleted automatically once the question is closed with that duplicate target. The link is at the top of your question and in the “Linked” sidebar.

Comment: Cool I search link of question :d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable strict mode, the error becomes a bit clearer:

```js
'use strict';
var functionVariable = function functionExpressionName() {
    functionExpressionName = 1;
    console.log(functionExpressionName) // function
};

functionVariable();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

The function name is un-*reassignable* inside the function, but you can create a *new* variable with the same name inside the function body. One way of looking at it is that the function name is declared with `const` just outside the function body:

```
var functionVariable = (() => {
  const functionExpressionName = function () {
    functionExpressionName = 1; // Clearly wrong - functionExpressionName is a const
    // but it would work if you declared a *new* variable,
    // which has a different lexical binding
    console.log(functionExpressionName) // function
  };
  return functionExpressionName; 
})();

functionVariable();
```

This isn't *exactly* what happens, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Make Sense Thank You Very Much :)